# WebUSB and driver for Windows

Tags: windows, winusb, webusb, libusbk

I want to use WebUSB with libusbK on Windows.

It looks like WebUSB works with WinUSB driver only. I couldn't make it work with libusbK.
I searched for a detailed paper but couldn't find anything.
I don't see any information about this at https://wicg.github.io/webusb/

Is it possible to use WebUSB with libusbK on Windows?

I have FTDI FT232H chip and I use libusbK driver for it.
Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" id="request-device">click me to list connected usb devices</button>

<script>
'use strict';

let button = document.getElementById('request-device');
button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  let device;
  let e;
  let filters;

  await navigator.usb.requestDevice({filters: []})
    .then(device => {
      console.log("vendorId:" + device.vendorId.toString(16) + 
         " productId:" + device.productId.toString(16));
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("There is no device. " + e);
    });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Chrome opens a popup window with nonexistent devices but my device is not on the list.
I re-installed driver to WinUSb by Zadig. Reboot computer. Start my code. And I see my device in the list.

Does WebUSB work with WinUSB drivers only (on Windows)?

Comment: I'm confused, what is your question exactly? Whether a library implements a standard? Questions need to be more specific, what errors are you seeing when using the library? What have you tried

Comment: I improved the question and explained what he did to fix it.

Comment: @fatihyildizhan  I add example

Answer (score 2):

Chrome does not officially support the libusb0 or libusbK drivers, only the WinUSB driver that is included with Windows.

Comment: Is this described anywhere?